# Angular Material does not work version Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to use Material with Angular 7?

My package.json:

```js
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"popper": "^1.0.1",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
```

After compiling my project, I get a lot of warnings from `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`.

Comment: which version are you using of both @angular/core and @angular/material

Comment: Hi! "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",

Comment: I strongly suggest you consider changing your accepted answer because it will mislead users and create more problems in their application if followed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running this.

```
npm install -S @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm uninstall @angular/core
npm install -S @angular/core
```

Comment: This method will work too as you are basically updating your Angular version to 8 instead of downgrading your angular material to 7. Just make sure you're not breaking anything by upgrading to Angular 8. If you are just starting out your application, this should not be a problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` versions are 8 while your Angular version is 7. You need to change your `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` versions to 7.

First uninstall the old versions

```
npm uninstall --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Then install version 7

```
npm install --save @angular/material@7 @angular/cdk@7
```